# changing json data values with a select box in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I am trying to load different data via the values in my select and I am going off the choropleth example and I have the following

```
d3.json("data1.json", function (json) {
data = json;
counties.selectAll("path")    
.attr("class", quantize);        
 });

 d3.select("select").on("change", function () {
  //get value of select and replace data1.json above
    d3.selectAll("svg").json("path", this.value);


 });
```

But, I just cannot load the different values.